# ansible variable across hosts in one playbook

Tags: ansible

is it possible to store value in variable and use across multiple hosts. I found that it should work with set_fact so I tried it like this. But it's not working.

```
- hosts: db
     remote_user: root
     tasks:

     - name: set fact
       set_fact:
         zone_id: "app"
         subnet_id: 28
        when:  host_ip.find("10.1.30") != -1

        ....
 - hosts: ns01
     remote_user: root
     tasks:

    - name:
      debug:
        var: "{{ hostvars['db']['zone_id'] }}"

    ....
```

But i get following error "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: "hostvars['db']" is undefined".

Thanks

Comment: if you want to use global vars you can create a vars file in include vars file with include_vars in the pre task and use it.

Comment: I don't want global var. The value in variable zone_id is based on IP address. I have thereare multiple conditions and fir  different ip subnets I have different zone_id based on user input. And I need to use content of variable zone_id use in another hosts.

Answer (score 0):

`set_fact` is used to extract information from a host and save it for later. It's usefor for information that changes over time.

It will save the information as a regular variable, so you will be able to access it as `{{ zone_id }}`.

Host vars are used to store 'static' information about each host that is likely different between hosts, so if this zone does not change, put it in the host vars. If it is something you need to check at runtime, use set_fact

Comment: thanks for answer. Yes I am able to acess it as {{ zone_id }} but only on the same host. I have playbook with multiple hosts and I need to access variable from host ns.Fron ns host i get undefined variable error.